# Are there any drawbacks to using dynamic JPA endpoints in Camel?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

**CONTEXT**

I've been trying to create a generic persistence layer for my application using Camel (v2.23.0) and Hibernate(v5.3.7). I'm also using HikariCP as the connection pool. To implement this generic persistence layer, I'm using the Camel JPA component to construct the core persistence routes as follows:

```
from("direct:getEntityById")
                .toD("jpa:${header.entityClassName}?persistenceUnit=" + projectStage.toString() +
                        "&namedQuery=${header.entityClassSimpleName}.${header.queryName}");

from("direct:upsertEntity")
                .toD("jpa:${header.entityClassName}?usePersist=false&persistenceUnit=" + projectStage.toString());
```

In the DAO, I'm using a dynamic JPA endpoint, so that I can reuse the route for any JPA entity.

I'm calling these routes through a plain Java DAO class, as follows:

```
    ...
    public <T> Optional<T> getEntityById(Object id, String queryName, Class<T> clazz) throws GenericDAOException {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
            queryParams.put("id", id);
            List<T> entities = (List<T>) fluentProducerTemplate
                    .withHeader("id", id)
                    .withHeader("entityClassName", clazz.getName())
                    .withHeader("entityClassSimpleName", clazz.getSimpleName())
                    .withHeader("queryName", queryName)
                    .withHeader("CamelJpaParameters", queryParams)
                    .to("direct:getEntityById")
                    .request(List.class);

            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void upsertEntity(T entityObject) throws GenericDAOException  {
        try {
            fluentProducerTemplate
                    .withBody(entityObject)
                    .withHeader("entityClassName", entityObject.getClass().getName())
                    .to("direct:upsertEntity")
                    .request();
        }
        ...
    }
```

This is the configuration for my persistence unit:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="Production" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:postgresql://..."/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="..."/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="..."/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="<custom dialect>"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="25"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="70"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="300000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="600000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Also, my JPA component is being created using a specific EntityManagerFactory (so I'm assuming all JPA endpoints will be sharing the same factory). (Using CDI for dependency injections)

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("jpa")
public JpaComponent getComponent(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, EntityManager entityManager) {
    JpaComponent component = new JpaComponent();
    component.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    component.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
    component.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    return component;
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

As per the following doc: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/toD-eip.html, we should avoid creating endless dynamic endpoints, due to the excessive resource consumption. Since I'm working with the JPA component, I am especially concerned about the number of DB connections created, which could lead to application failures if not within a certain threshold.

To get around these potential issues, I'm using a connection pool. Since all JPA endpoints would use the same EntityManagerFactory, I presume that the connection pool would also be shared between these endpoints.

So I have the following questions:

1. When exactly would the JPA route release the DB connection? (as in, are they released immediately after the JPA route has completed processing a message, or are the connections tied to the lifecycle of the JPA endpoints?)
2. Would a new dynamic JPA endpoint be created for each unique URI?
3. What are the other potential issues that I would need to be wary of, when using dynamic JPA endpoints? (I suppose memory consumption would be one).

Comment: Camel is a EIP toolkit so you really have a mismatch in what you are trying to achieve and what camel is about.